# Extracting text between parenthesis in columns in dataframe into new columns in dataframes

Tags: r, regex, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe called reasons with columns where in some rows, there is text that have numbers in parenthesis.  The format is like this.

```
concern                          notaware           scenery
(2) chat community (4) more      
(1) didn't know                  (1) beautiful      (3) stunning
(3) often                                           (1) always
```

Reproducible version:

```
structure(list(concern = c("(2) chat community (4) more", "(1) didn't know", 
"(3) often"), notaware = c("", "(1) beautiful", ""), scenery = c("", 
"(3) stunning", "(1) always")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want a new data frame with just the parenthesis and numbers

```
concern                          notaware            scenery
(2) (4) 
(1)                             (1)                (3) 
(3)                             (1)
```

I realise there is a similar question here but the data is not in a column

[Extracting data into new columns using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951918/extracting-data-into-new-columns-using-r)

and this but it doesn't seem to apply to a dataframe

[Extract info inside all parenthesis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613237/extract-info-inside-all-parenthesis-in-r)

From the questions I've looked up I've tried to cobble a workaround.  I tried

```
reasons %>% mutate(concern1 = str_match(concern, pattern = "\\(.*?\\)"))
```

Which resulted in an unchanged dataframe.

And this

```
reasons$concern1 <- sub(regmatches(reasons$concern, gregexpr(pat, reasons$concern, perl=TRUE)))
```

Which comes up with this

```
Error in sub(regmatches(UltraCodes$concern, gregexpr(pat, 
UltraCodes$concern,  : 
argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I looked at this which I know is a duplicate of the second question but it made more sense to me.

[Using R to parse and return text in parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359738/using-r-to-parse-and-return-text-in-parenthesis)

And I used

```
pat <- "(?<=\\()([^()]*)(?=\\))"
concern1 <- regmatches(reasons$concern, gregexpr(pat, reasons$concern, 
perl=TRUE))
```

This gives me a list with a name and a type and a value - the values are what I want even though its '2' rather than (2)

So I figure I can make multiple lists and try to put them into a dataframe so I make a list notaware1 out of column notaware and so on.  I have a feeling that the blank values are throwing things of as I try

```
reasons1 <-data.frame(concern1, notaware1)
reasons1 <-as.data.frame(concern1, notaware1)
```

Which gives me

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = 
TRUE,  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1, 2
```

Which I don't quite understand as all my lists are the same lengths, I feel I'm misunderstanding some fundamentals here.

Next I thought I could do a wrap around by exporting the list to csv, but the answers I've found seem to want me to turn the list into a dataframe first, which is my problem.

Then I find this

```
reasons$concern3 <-paste(concern1)
```

Which does add the list to my dataframe, and I can repeat this for all my lists.

However it is a bit messy as blanks are now given as character(0), one bracket is single numbers and where there are two brackets is c("2", "9") so my columns now look like this

```
concern                          adventure          scenery
c("2", "9")                      character(0)       character(0)
1                                1                  3
3                                1                  character(0)
```

But I have something that I can put into a csv file to tidy.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
 data.frame(gsub("[^()0-9]","",as.matrix(dat)))

  concern notaware scenery
1  (2)(4)                 
2     (1)      (1)     (3)
3     (3)              (1)
```

## EDIT

```
 data.frame(gsub("(?<!\\))(?:\\w+|[^()])(?!\\))","",as.matrix(dat),perl=T))
   concern notaware scenery
1 (2) (4)                  
2     (1)      (1)     (3) 
3     (3)              (1)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.  That is much simpler!  The only thing is I just realised there numbers in my text that aren't in parenthesis which I'm not interested in.

Comment: @Lan are there any spaces in the parenthesis??

Comment: There are no spaces in the paraenthesis

Answer (score 0):

What we do here, is loop the data.frame by column and use `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` package to extract all numbers in parentheses.

Since there can be multiple values to extract from a single cell, we need `str_extract_all` with the `simplify=T` argument, which returns a data.frame for each column (rows are rows in `df` with a column for each match  found).

We then need to go through those tables with `apply` to bind each row together into a single character vector (separated by a space here, but you can change that). Now, we just have a `vector` for each column, so `apply` can stitch them together nicely into a data.frame.

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) {
    temp <- stringr::str_extract_all(x, '\\([0-9]\\)', simplify = T)
    apply(temp, 1, paste0, collapse = ' ')
})

     concern   notaware scenery
[1,] "(2) (4)" ""       ""     
[2,] "(1) "    "(1)"    "(3)"  
[3,] "(3) "    ""       "(1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything except number and brackets with gsub:

```
     data <- cbind("concern" = c("(2) chat community (4) more ", "(1) didn't know ", "(3) often  "), notaware=c("", "(2) chat community", "" ) )  

      gsub("[^0-9\\(\\)]", "", data)
```